# How do I create a 3d wireframe object/low poly outline illustration?

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d, cinema4d, wireframing

I'm trying to create something similar to the images below. I have Cinema 4D but need some guidance. Thanks :)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve these output with the help of any vector based tools like illustrator.

For Cinema 4D, you can follow these steps... [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W30IkcniJ9E) and then tweak your output image in Photoshop or GIMP