# Geometric mosaic effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

Using Photoshop or Illustrator, what would be the easiest way to recreate the geometric mosaic effect seen below on an image? I realize the image below was likely hand drawn and recreating it in an automated fashion would yield different results but I'm just looking for the tools that may exist to recreate something similar.

[image: wolf-geo]

Comment: @WELZ I don't think it is low poly art. This looks more like wireframe art to me. Which I consider to be a totally different yet similar style. So I do not consider this exactly a duplicate

Comment: @LateralTerminal, You are correct that it is different, however the process of creating it is exactly the same. (just at the end you make it only outlines and no fill)

Comment: Yes, I agree that you can use that method to create similar results, but if you claim this as duplicate than someone who has a different approach to this won't be able to answer. Someone else might have a special approach or program to help for this specifically since its not exactly low poly art. It's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called *low-poly* or *low-polygon* art.

A simple search yields many results but bear in mind that **NONE will be as good as manually creating the effect**.

---

## Here are some options

1. [Dmesh is a free program with options to upgrade](http://dmesh.thedofl.com/)
2. [A nice tutorial from SpoonGraphics](https://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/tutorials/create-geometric-low-poly-art-easy-way)
3. [A list of several more options](https://www.noupe.com/essentials/freebies-tools-templates/low-poly-trend-six-free-generators-for-backgrounds-and-images-84108.html)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a program that will automate a flat image to look like a 3D wireframe.

Ovaryraptor's answer is good but it is covering low poly art.

This looks like wireframe to me which is similar but different and does not apply to this question.

You basically need to imagine what it would look like as a 3D low polygon count object and draw where you think the lines would go. This helps if you have a little understanding of what 3D objects look like in wireframe mode.

Here is something someone 3D printed. That might help give you a better idea of what a wireframe of a 3D object might look like. I also thought it was fitting that it had part of the object on the left filled in. That is kind of like the effect of the image you provided.

Also look at [How do I create a 3d wireframe object/low poly outline illustration?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/87225/how-do-i-create-a-3d-wireframe-object-low-poly-outline-illustration)

Possible duplicate.

[image]

Here is a picture from the possible duplicate. Which the answer was to use 3D software. But for your purposes its probably just be faster to guess what it would like like and draw the lines manually than it would be to recreate flat art in a 3D program then produce wireframe later.
[image]